# how do I find the shortest path distance while using recursion in a for loop?

Tags: java

I wrote the following code:

```java
public static int findShortestPath(int[][] m, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (findPath(m, i, j) == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (m[i][j] == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (m[i][j] == 0) {
        int[] lst = new int[m.length];
        Arrays.fill(lst, 0);
        for (int k = 0; k < m.length; k++) {
            if (m[i][k] == 1) {
                m[i][k] = 0;
                return 1 + findShortestPath(m, k, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

which finds a path between two points. However I need to find the shortest path, so instead of:

```java
if (m[i][j] == 0) {
    int[] lst = new int[m.length];
    Arrays.fill(lst, 0);
    for (int k = 0; k < m.length; k++) {
        if (m[i][k] == 1) {
            m[i][k] = 0;
            return 1 + findShortestPath(m, k, j);
        }
        
    }   
}
```

for the line `return 1+findShortestPath(m,k,j);` I need to store each value in the loop and compare them. How can I do that?
(the matrix represents an unweighted directed graph)
Examples:

```
findShortestPath ([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],0,1) -> -1 findShortestPath ([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],1,1) -> 0 findShortestPath ([[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0]],0,2) ->2 
findShortestPath ([[0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0]],0,2) -> 2
```

Comment: You have `2D` matrix and to get two points you should have 4 coordinates. But you have only 2!

Comment: the matrix represents a graph, which means if point m[i][j]==1, then there is a path with distance 1 from i to j.

Comment: Are 0 and 1 the only possible values in the matrix?

Comment: yes only 0 and 1 are possible values

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```java
public class Main {

    private static final int NONE = -1;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        int[][] m = {
                { NONE, NONE, 26, NONE, 38, NONE, NONE, NONE },
                { NONE, NONE, NONE, 29, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE },
                { NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, 34 },
                { NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, 52, NONE },
                { NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE, 35, NONE, 37 },
                { NONE, 32, NONE, NONE, 35, NONE, NONE, 28 },
                { 58, NONE, 4, NONE, 93, NONE, NONE, NONE },
                { NONE, NONE, NONE, 39, NONE, 28, NONE, NONE }
        };

        int src = 0;
        int dest = 6;
        int path = findShortestPath(m, src, dest);
        System.out.println(path);    // 151
    }

    public static int findShortestPath(int[][] m, int src, int dest) {
        return dfs(m, src, dest, new boolean[m.length]);
    }

    private static int dfs(int[][] m, int cur, int dest, boolean[] visited) {
        if (cur == dest)
            return 0;
        if (cur < 0 || cur >= visited.length || visited[cur])
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        visited[cur] = true;
        int path = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int col = 0; col < visited.length; col++) {
            if (m[cur][col] == NONE)
                continue;

            int res = dfs(m, col, dest, visited);

            if (res != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                path = Math.min(path, m[cur][col] + dfs(m, col, dest, visited));
        }

        visited[cur] = false;

        return path;
    }

}
```

Example from: [Sedgewick, Wayne - Algorithms, 4th ed](http://index-of.es/Varios-2/Algorithms%204th%20Edition.pdf)